# When fliping the character the rotation of character's weapon goes backward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I have two game objects on the Scene, 1.Character(Parent Object) and 2.Weapon(Child Object) . The problem is when the character is moving to the right side, the rotation of the weapon is fine, it is toward where character is facing and rotating as expected, as you can see in the Gif image attach below. But when i Flip to left side everything goes wrong, the weapon goes backward and when i press down arrow the rotation goes up and when press up arrow the rotation goes down, see the Gif image attach below.. Please help How to Fix it.

Here is my Code:

```
 public float weaponRotationSpeed = 13f;

 private Animator anim;
 private float angle;

 void Awake()
 {
     anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
 }

 void Update()
 {
     Vector2 hv = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
     Vector3 changeParentScale = transform.localScale;

     if (hv != Vector2.zero)
     {
         if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
         {
             changeParentScale.x = -5f;
             transform.localScale = changeParentScale;
         }
         else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
         {
             changeParentScale.x = 5f;
             transform.localScale = changeParentScale;
         }


         angle = Mathf.Atan2(hv.y, hv.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

         transform.Find("Weapon").rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.Find("Weapon").rotation,
             Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle),
             weaponRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

         anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
     }
     else
     {
         anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
     }
```

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you probably would want to flip the rotation then as well? E.g. using [`Mathf.Sign`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sign.html)

```
Quaternion.Euler(0,0, angle * Mathf.Sign(changeParentScale.x))
```

There are some other little flaws in your code!

- You shouldn't use `Find` each frame .. rather store it **once**.
- You are using `GetAxis` repeatedly and should also store the vaues the first time .. don't you already have them in `hv`?
- `Lerp` is quite cool tool but you are using it wrong ;) It interpolates each frame using the given factor .. usually you want a fixed one like e.g. `0.5f` and not using `Time.deltaTime`

It should probably rather be something like

```
 // You will have to adjust this value again
 // This needs to be a constant value between 0 and 1
 //  - 0: rotation isn't updated at all
 //  - 1: rotation immediately jumps to target
 //  - e.g. 0.5f: rotation is every frame set to the middle between current and target
 [Range(0f, 1f)]
 public float weaponRotationSpeed = 0.5f;

 // already reference these via the Inspector
 [SerializeField] private Animator anim;
 [SerializeField] private Transform weapon;
 private float angle;

 // As Fallback get them ONCE on runtime
 void Awake()
 {
     if(!anim) anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
     if(!weapon) weapon = transform.Find("Weapon");
 }

 void Update()
 {
     Vector2 hv = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
     Vector3 changeParentScale = transform.localScale;

     if (hv != Vector2.zero)
     {
         // get direction of Horizontal
         int sign = Mathf.Sign(hv.x);

         if (!Mathf.Approximately(hv.x, 0))
         {
             changeParentScale.x = 5f * sign;
             transform.localScale = changeParentScale;
         }

         angle = Mathf.Atan2(hv.y, hv.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

         weapon.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(weapon.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle * sign), weaponRotationSpeed);

         anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
     }
     else
     {
         anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
     }
 }
```

---

Alternatively you could probably also already solve it by not using `rotation` but `localRotation` for rotating the weapon.

Comment: thankz, i write these lines inside nested if >> Vector3 childScale = weapon.localScale; childScale.x = 0.05f * sign; weapon.localScale = childScale; ........ its working fine now.. thank you :)